Was it a custom to offer a dancer that pleased you anything at all? Like in King Herod’s case
Mark 6:22 stated,

When the daughter of Herodias came in and danced, she pleased Herod and his dinner guests. The king said to the girl, “Ask me for anything you want, and I’ll give it to you.

Was the King supposed to offer anything? Was it custom?

SE is a bad place to ask questions that require Yes/no answers.  Those questions overlap with trivial questions.  Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

IMHO, this is not a case of custom, but is one of two things (Possibly both). First, a monarch exercising the monarch's obligation of generosity, or second, an ex post facto fiction to explain court intrigue. Dr. J. Salisbury argues  that Herod's wife used Salome to manipulate Herod against politico/religious opponents. In that interpretation the whole event was scripted.  Or it could be both. Additional commentary at genderhistory

yes, the prior comment perhaps should be an answer; I don't have the time or effort to work it into a minimum quality answer, so I'm providing it in the hope it will assist research


When the daughter of Herodias came and danced, she pleased Herod and
his guests, and the king said to the girl, “Ask me for whatever you
wish, and I will give it to you.” 23And he swore to her, “Whatever you
ask of me, I will give you, up to half my kingdom!”

The terminology used by Herod in this section of scripture is actually used previously in the Old Testament - in the book of Esther. One could submit that this is a common "turn of phrase" or colloquialism for Kings or Rulers of the time and culture. There are however also many parallels between the circumstances of these two stories and so it could also be seen as this story making a direct reference to the Esther story by the choice of words used.
Esther 5:1 (also again in 5:6 and 7:2)

On the third day Esther put on her royal robes and stood in
the inner court of the palace, in front of the king’s hall. The king
was sitting on his royal throne in the hall, facing the entrance. 2
When he saw Queen Esther standing in the court, he was pleased with
her and held out to her the gold scepter that was in his hand. So
Esther approached and touched the tip of the scepter.
3 Then the king asked, “What is it, Queen Esther? What is your
request? Even up to half the kingdom, it will be given you.”

Biblical stories will often make use of "repeating narrative patterns" which don't reoccur exactly as before but use previous themes with important inversions or changes. An example would be the repeating pattern of the woman at the well. (eg: Compare Abrahams servant and Rebekah Gen24 vs Jesus and the Samaritan woman John4)
In this case the previous story of Ester occurs during the Persian diaspora. A young Jewish woman finds favor with the foreign king, becomes queen, and risks her life to save the Jewish people from destruction when the court official Haman persuades the king to authorize genocide against all the Jews of the empireand kill a righteous Jewish man named Mordecai. The woman uses her beauty and position as Queen to persuade the foreign king to save the Jewish people and has the man who seeks to destroy them - Haman - killed by im hanging on a pole outside the city while the Jewish man Mordecai is honoured by the king and paraded through the street in Royal garments on a royal horse. There should be lots of prophetic connections popping to mind with this story.
In Mark 6:22 we see a similar set of circumstance but with almost a complete inversion of the story. With the Jews again ruled over by a foreign power - this time by Rome with a vassal king - Herod. He is married to an unrighteous adulterous Jewish wife Herodias - formerly the wife of his brother Philip who has been accused of sexual immorality by a righteous prophet (John the Baptist). She uses her power and daughters beauty and skill to have the righteous and holy man of God who seeks to save the Jewish people and turn them back to God killed for pointing out her and Herods own sin.
Its basically an inversion of the original Esther story and I believe this line and the kings offer is being used by the author of Mark as a deliberate reference\hyperlink back to the previous story in Esther.
Esther is shown as a righteous Queen who risks her life and uses her power and influence to save a righteous Jewish man and the Jewish people and kills an unrighteous man who seeks to destroy them. (Self Sacrifice for the greater good)
vs
Herodias as an unrighteous Queen who uses her power and influence to kill a righteous man who seeks to help and save the Jewish people in order to protect herself from his accusations against her and her Husbands own sin. (Self preservation at the expense of the greater good)

Thank you. Although I asked if this was something the king had to do. If it was a custom or something to be expected. I understand now that it wasn’t something he had to do/offer. I did learn that Herodias was Jewish. I had no idea. Thanks!

No problem. Yes I know the answer didn't strictly answer the question but I was trying to point to the fact the statement here is likely being used as a "literary device" to draw connections and comparisons with the Esther story.  A "motif".  Herod wasn't even a true king - he was what's known as a tetrach under Rome and didn't have authority to give away anything. Even if it was an established hyperbolic custom to represent gaining the kings favor - it's being used here to link the two stories to juxtapose the leadership. See this link: https://youtu.be/isBKoIORntI?si=AM-St-BNDJp_G_Qe

There are no other cases mentioned in the Bible. There are a number of factors that come into play here.

This was a birthday celebration and Herod (Antipas) must have been feeling both generous and more than a little tipsy.

Herodias had previously been the wife of Herod Philip (although historical sources are are not clear about this). Thus her daughter's relationship with her step father Antipas was likely to be difficult. Her dance was not only delightful in itself but was also a sign of her wanting to please her stepfather, who responded with generosity.

The whole scene may have been a ruse, arranged beforehand to give Antipas an excuse for executing the Baptist, who was popular among the people.


Although the Bible does not relate another case of a dancer being richly rewarded by a king, there is one biblical precedent that we ought to consider: Queen Esther's request to King Xerxes. In Esther 5, she dresses in all her finery and appears before him in court, which pleases him greatly, so much that he tells her :

“Now what is your petition? It will be given you. And what is your
request? Even up to half the kingdom, it will be granted.”

Of course Esther was not a dancer. She was the king's wife, who pleased him by her attire and demeanor rather than by performing a dance. As far as I know this is the only other such event mentioned in the Bible. Such rewards may have been customary in some royal courts, but the Bible only contains these two examples.

Dan, I tried in vain to correct a typo in your line 5 where the word 'again' was repeated 'again'! Some change has now been made to proposed edits preventing me submitting it. It will not be put in the review queue before submission as the edit needs 6 characters or more! How can I add anything to what only needs subtracting? I posted a Q on this in History Meta and it seems I can only flag this up for the OP's attention for him or her to do themselves. Weird, or what? It never used to be like that.  My proof-reading skills might go to waste now... +1 despite the typo (joking!)

@Anne -- and I don't find the word "again" anywhere my post or the edits! I wish this Q had not been moved here as my answer is based on the biblical record, not history in general. Well, at least I am gaining reputation here on this site. Anyway, I appreciate your edits. I am often shocked at how many typos I create.

Yes, your original answer was well suited to the original posting in biblical Hermeneutics. But now I think I might be going loopy, for line 5 has "are are" and not "again again". I best go lie down in a quiet, darkened room...
